# Handlebars Template is giving me undefine error

Tags: javascript, templates, handlebars.js

I have a WebSql query results i am trying to template with Handlebars, however when i compile and run it shows nothing on the webpage.
When i console.log the template Handlebars is throwing this error to the console. 
"Error: You must pass a string or Handlebars AST to Handlebars.compile. You passed undefined " at handlebars line 2523.
I am confuse because when i copy the sql results and place it literally it compiles.

This a sample of the sql results
PLEASE NOTE: I am a newbies.

```
{ 
    deleted: "0" 
    lastModified : "2013-12-17 11:42:11" 
    mesID : "201" 
    message : "Good morning Mr Amos" 
    subID : "18"
}
```

THIS IS MY JAVASCRIPT

```
function loadMessageList(subID){
    $("#messageDetailList").empty();
    db.transaction (function(tx) {
        tx.executeSql('SELECT * FROM MESSAGETB WHERE subID ="'+ subID +'"', 
            [], function (tx, results) {
                var len = results.rows.length;
                var obj = [];            
                for(var i = 0; i<len; i++) {
                 obj[i] = results.rows.item(i);
                }
                var obj2 = obj;
                renderTemplate(obj2);
        });
    });    
}    

function renderTemplate (obj2){
    var template = Handlebars.compile($('#messageDetail-template').html());
    $('#messageDetailList').append(template(obj2));     
}
```

THIS IS MY HTML

```
<div data-role="page" id="messageDetail">
    <div data-role="header">
        <h1>Header</h1>
    </div>
    <div data-role="content">
        <ul id="messageDetailList" data-role="listview">
            <script id="messageDetail-template" 
                type="text/x-handlebars-template">   
                {{#each}}
                <li>
                    <div class="phil-legend">
                        <span class="my-message">{{message}}<br /></span>
                        <span class="sent-mesid">{{mesID}}<br /></span>
                        <span class="my-subid">{{subID}}<br /></span>
                        <span class="my-modified">{{lastModified}}<br /></span>
                        <span class="my-deleted">{{deleted}}<br /></span>
                    </div>
                </li>       
                {{/each}}    
                </script>  
        </ul>
    </div>
    <div data-role="footer">
        <h4>Footer</h4>
    </div>
</div>
```

I really dont know what i am doing wrong. I will be glad if anyone can help me solve this problem. it is really giving me a real head-knock. Thank you in advance

Comment: Are you running your code in a `$.ready` block? Do you see  the correct template HTML if you do `console.log($('#messageDetail-template').html());` before compiling?

Comment: @loganfsmyth thank you for your responds. when i console.log($('#messageDetail-template').html()); it gives me undefined. I have update my HTML. the page is being rendered in a Jquerymobile page.

Comment: What is calling `loadMessageList`? Does it work if you put the `messageDetail-template` script tag in the `<head>` above your scripts?

Comment: I move the template script tag to the head of my page and it work, thank you man. am i allow to answer the question myself??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that you are calling your `loadMessageList` before the browser has finished loading and parsing the page HTML. e.g. `$('#messageDetail-template').length === 0` because the template tag hasn't been processed yet.

You have two options:

1. Move the `#messageDetail-template` element above the place in your code where you call `loadMessageList` so that it is found properly
2. Wait for the page to have been fully loaded/processed before calling `loadMessageList`. e.g. `$.ready(function(){ ... });`

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
 JSON.stringify(obj2)
```

before passing to the template